# How to get the value of kerning pair from the table?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-text

I get CGGlyph

```
let a = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(font, "A" as CFString)
let v = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(font, "V" as CFString)
```

i get a link to the table

```
let kernData = CTFontCopyTable(font, CTFontTableTag(kCTFontTableKern), CTFontTableOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

kerning table

```
let kerningTable = CFDataGetBytePtr(kernData)
```

Comment: Did you ever get it done?